# Overview on hospitals and medical services - in America, Asia, Africa and Europe

Tags: data-request, medical, openstreetmap

I am looking for a overview on hospitals and medical services provided by the public (and also by the private) healthcare sector in Europe, Asia America and Australia.

```
public hospitals
private hospitals and medical clinics ...
```

I am looking for all the European Countries.

Requirements for each item:

```
name
address
postal code
town
street
website
(and email address)
```

Note: I know that I can approach with an OpenStreetMap attempt - but if there are some datasets & or sites that we can scrape & parse.